# (Pandas) to_scv erro no parametro sep=

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Estou tentando jogar o conteúdo de um dataset em um scv, porem o parâmetro **SEP =';'** parou de funcionar.

```
df.to_csv(path,r'\20191122_Consolidados_camara_de_retencao.csv', sep = ';')
```

Ao tentar executar a linha de comando o Python da o seguinte erro:

```
to_csv() got multiple values for argument 'sep'
```

Alguém já passou por esse problema ? Consegue me ajudar a entender o erro ?

Obrigado.

Comment: O segundo parâmetro de `to_csv` já é o `sep`, então você está passando um valor pela posição, `r'\20191122_Consolidados_camara_de_retencao.csv'`, e outro pelo parâmetro nomeado, `sep = ';'`. Ou seja, a chamada da função está errada. Recomendo que revise a [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) e veja como fazer devidamente o que precisa.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário Woss, mas poderia me dar um exemplo de como eu passaria um separado < ; > neste caso ?

Eu até olhei a documentação e no exemplo esta passando o separador igual eu fiz. Fiquei confuso. rs

Comment: O que é `path` e `r'\20191122_Consolidados_camara_de_retencao.csv'` que também passou por parâmetros?

Comment: path = os.chdir('C:\\Users\\ADAMLINCOLNOLIVEIRAS\\Box Sync\\Diretorio_Camara_de_Retencao')
e 
r'\20191122_Consolidados_camara_de_retencao.csv' 
é o nome do arquivo que eu quero que o carquivo tenha até onde eu sei.

Comment: Mas por que passar dois caminhos para a função? Você não deveria concatená-los e montar apenas um caminho?

Comment: é por que o PATH é o caminho da pasta onde estão outros arquivos.

Com o comando (path, r'\20191122_Consolidados_camara_de_retencao.csv')

Estou na verdade montando um caminho só:

C:\\Users\\ADAMLINCOLNOLIVEIRAS\\Box Sync\\Diretorio_Camara_de_Retencao + /20191122_Consolidados_camara_de_retencao.csv

Isso funcionava antes, mas o Pandas atualizou e agora esta diferente.

Comment: Não, você está passando os dois valroes separadamente para a função, sendo o segundo considerado como `sep`. Se quer concatenar, utilize o operador `+`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101374/discussion-between-adam-lincoln-and-woss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.to_csv('20191122_Consolidados_camara_de_retencao.csv', sep = ';')
```

Dessa fora é salvo no mesmo diretório do arquivo .py. Se for querer definir outro diretório, pode usar por exemplo:

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Users\Desktop\20191122_Consolidados_camara_de_retencao.csv', sep = ';')
```

Comment: O erro estava sendo causado pela tentativa de concatenar o Caminho do arquivo (Path) e o nome do arquivo, dessa forma o Python identificava que eu estava passando dois parâmetros SEP=, já que o primeiro parâmetro sempre precisa ser um SEP nesse caso.